# (Python/Selenium) Dictionary is missing elements

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary

I'm webscraping wellrx.com. I'm trying to create a dictionary for each page that I scrape and adding that page to an csv file.

I am getting the name and price on one page, clicking a link to get to the alternative drug name/price and getting the name and price for that page.

Ex: Dictionaries should be

{'drug name': 'ARIPIPRAZOLE', 'price': '$16.45', 'other name': 'ABILIFY', 'price1': '$892.59'}

{'drug name': 'PIOGLITAZONE HCL', 'price': '$9.00', 'other name': 'ACTOS', 'price1': '$392.11'}

but I just get

{'drug name': 'PIOGLITAZONE HCL', 'price': '$9.00', 'other name': 'ACTOS', 'price1': '$392.11'}

```
#get drug name and price 
pages_dict = {}
        try:
            drug_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h4[@class="displayName skel skel-displayName"]').text 
            price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@class="right pr2"]').text
            pages_dict['drug name'] = drug_name
            pages_dict['price'] = price
            print(pages_dict)
        except:
            continue
#click the alternative name 
        try:    
            name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h5[@id="OtherName"]').text
            name1 = re.findall(": (.*)", name)[0]
            driver.find_element_by_link_text(name1).click()
            time.sleep(5)
#other drug name 
            other_name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h4[@class="displayName skel skel-displayName"]').text 
            price1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@class="right pr2"]').text
            pages_dict['other name'] = other_name
            pages_dict['price1'] = price1
            print(pages_dict)
        except:
            continue
```

Comment: `{ (drug1 : $5), (drug2: $2) }` is not a dictionary though. Plus how does this (drug1: $5) work? is this a string?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add a line of code.

Comment: NEVER MIND. THANK YOU FOR EVERYONE WHO COMMENT. I'M STUPID AND I RAN THE CODE AGAIN AND IT WORKS FINE. NOW TO FIX THE NEXT BUG

Answer (score 1):

I think you have first to learn about [dictionaries](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/), because you are always overwriting the same key with:

```
pages_dict['drug name'] = drug_name
pages_dict['price'] = price
```

just try:

```
pages_dict[drug_name] = drug_name
pages_dict[price] = price
```

and you will see how different keys are store with different values.

If you wish to store the price for every drug it would be more reasonable to do something like this:

```
pages_dict[drug_name] = price
```

If you instead want the same kind of dict with fixed keys representing one instance I suggest you to create a list of dictionaries:

```
list_of_dicts = []
pages_dict = {}

# Put a block code who creates page_dict
list_of dicts.append(pages_dict)
# Put a block code who creates page_dict
list_of dicts.append(pages_dict)
# Put a block code who creates page_dict
list_of dicts.append(pages_dict)

for pages in list_of_dicts:
    print(pages)
```

But this is obvious not a nice way to implement. You should use some iteration (for or while) through the pages. The code you posted needs a lot of revision. It's quite unreadable.

Comment: ah. Sorry I'm new to stack. without the whole code it is confusing. I've updated it.

Comment: @HankYun I've edited the answer and I hope that helps getting closer to what you want.